# How to call a function in an if statement?

Tags: python

AFTER HELP FROM Ahmet Bilgin

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkIIH.png)

[PYTHON SHELL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5DAp.png)

---

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6vFV.png)

[PYTHON SHELL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol912.png)

I am trying to call an def function inside a `if` statement but when I do so it doesn't work and just goes back to the python shell.

I don't know what to do I've tried some things I know of and searched google but can't seem to find anything.

```
def main2():
    print("Vul hieronder de tekst die je wilt ontsleutelen.")
    dec_word = input("> ")
    print("Vul hieronder de cijfer van de verschuiving. (Van 1 tot 25!)")
    dec_keys = int(input("> "))
    allowed_numbers = list(range(1, 26))
    while dec_keys not in allowed_numbers:
        print("Foute Optie!")
        dec_keys = int(input("> "))

    dec_decrypted = decrypt(dec_keys,dec_word)
    print("Ontsleuteld:"+ dec_decrypted +".")
    print("Ontsleuteling van:"+ dec_word +".")
    print("Verschuiving: "+ str(dec_keys) +".")
    input("prompt:")

def main():
    print("Vul hieronder de tekst die je wilt versleutelen.")
    word = input("> ")
    print("Vul hieronder de cijfer van de verschuiving. (Van 1 tot 25!)")
    allowed_numbers = list(range(1, 26))
    keys = int(input("> "))
    while keys not in allowed_numbers:
        print("Foute Optie!")
        keys = int(input("> "))

    encrypted = encrypt(keys,word)
    print("Versleuteling: "+ encrypted +".")
    decrypted = decrypt(keys,encrypted)
    print("Versleuteld van: "+ decrypted +".")
    print("Verschuiving: "+ str(keys) +".")
    input("prompt:")


print("Wil je een woord ontsleutelen of versleutelen")
choice1 = input("> ")
allowed_choices = ["ontsleutelen", "versleutelen"]
while choice1.lower() not in allowed_choices:
print("Foute Optie!")
    choice1 = input("> ")
    if choice1.lower() == ("versleutelen"):
        main()
    if choice1.lower() == ("ontsleutelen"):
        main2()
```

The problem is when I type input for choice1.lower() either "versleutelen" and "ontsleutelen" it does't continue main() or main2()

Comment: Everything inside a function is supposed to be indented, but none of your function definitions have indented code after them; either your indentation is totally wrong or you've just pasted it here incorrectly. can you edit your post so that the indentation is correct, considering that indentation is a crucial part of Python's control flow?

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: How can this ever be true: `choice1.lower() == ("Versleutelen")`? You've made one string lower case and you're comparing it to one that has upper case.

Comment: lines of code after its def definition are written with 4 spaces. Did you miss this or did you have trouble copying it?

Comment: @MarkM that has to be it, since the issue is so trivial I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation of the code in your question think it was just a posting problem, but after reading the comments I see it may have the way your code really was — in which case I may have solved the program for you.

Comment: I've tried what you said @Mark M, sadly didn't work. I'm quite new to python so sorry for that....

Comment: Also, thanks for the correcting of my text. 
I did have trouble copying it over so i posted an screenshot @AhmetBilgin, everything seems to be fine (no unneeded spaces) in the code.

Comment: @martineau I've tried copying the code over but it gives me an error: "expected an indented block" at print("Foute Optie") [After "while choice1.lower() not in allowed_choices:"]

Comment: Indeed, it looks like I missed indenting that call to the `print()` function. Sorry. Indentation is very significant in Python and has to be done correctly.

Comment: @martineau I think I did what you said, but it did not work it still goes back to python shell.

Comment: As you presumable now know, the  only changes I made to the code in your question were to indent it, not change its logic — which apparently was also a problem. For future reference see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I also have the solution organized:

Try replacing line 74 with: `choice1 = ""`

If you noticed, you are asking for another input before the while loop. and then you go into the loop. Try deleting row 74 and assign a different value for choice. because even if you enter the correct word, it will misunderstand it in the while loop because it is on the list. If you delete line 74, it will not be enough, because choice1.lower () not in allowed_choices: will show the error choice was not found.

```
def main2():
    print("Vul hieronder de tekst die je wilt ontsleutelen.")
    dec_word = input("> ")
    print("Vul hieronder de cijfer van de verschuiving. (Van 1 tot 25!)")
    dec_keys = int(input("> "))
    allowed_numbers = list(range(1, 26))
    while dec_keys not in allowed_numbers:
        print("Foute Optie!")
        dec_keys = int(input("> "))

    dec_decrypted = decrypt(dec_keys,dec_word)
    print("Ontsleuteld:"+ dec_decrypted +".")
    print("Ontsleuteling van:"+ dec_word +".")
    print("Verschuiving: "+ str(dec_keys) +".")
    input("prompt:")

def main():
    print("Vul hieronder de tekst die je wilt versleutelen.")
    word = input("> ")
    print("Vul hieronder de cijfer van de verschuiving. (Van 1 tot 25!)")
    allowed_numbers = list(range(1, 26))
    keys = int(input("> "))
    while keys not in allowed_numbers:
        print("Foute Optie!")
        keys = int(input("> "))

    encrypted = encrypt(keys,word)
    print("Versleuteling: "+ encrypted +".")
    decrypted = decrypt(keys,encrypted)
    print("Versleuteld van: "+ decrypted +".")
    print("Verschuiving: "+ str(keys) +".")
    input("prompt:")


print("Wil je een woord ontsleutelen of versleutelen")
choice1 = ""
allowed_choices = ["ontsleutelen", "versleutelen"]
while choice1.lower() not in allowed_choices:
    choice1 = input("> ")
    if choice1.lower() == ("versleutelen"):
        main()
    if choice1.lower() == ("ontsleutelen"):
        main2()
```

Comment: @Sebastian I see that you corrected your question and changed it. I couldn't understand why you had trouble showing your code.

Comment: I tried changing my code to that.... did not work sadly.

Comment: @Sebastian Could I explain the explanation I made?

Comment: Ok, so i changed from this: choice1 = input("> ") to this: choice1 = "". 
And nou it gives me an error like wrong option, i also read in your comment that it supposed to do that but after that i lost you... i don't understand what i have to do next.... so yes i would like the explanation.

Comment: @Sebastian i tried the code the way i said and it was not giving any error. The main functions were also working. I'll edit the comment and add the codes.

Comment: I have editted the post with more screenshots.

Comment: @Sebastian So is there any mistake you get? or is there somewhere you don't understand?

Comment: I understand now. It works like it should thanks!!